# handler method in spring boot is saving new record instead of updating already existed record in database for put request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, put

I am trying to update an existing record in my database for a put request in spring boot.

Incoming Request -

[image]

Handler method in controller class

```java
  // put method for updating record
    @PutMapping("/accounts/{id}")
    public Account putAccount(@RequestBody Account account, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        System.out.println(account);
        Account ac = this.accountServices.addAccount(account);
        // save method of crud repository also updates if data is already present
        return ac;
    }
```

AccountServices class addAccount() method

```java
// add an account
    public Account addAccount(Account account) {
        Account acc = this.accountRepository.save(account);
        return acc;
    }
```

AccountRepository interface

```java
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer> {
//custom finder method to get book record with id
}
```

For every request it is adding new record instead of updating already existing record.
Someone please help here.

Adding Account class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int accountNumber;
    public String accountType;
    public int balance;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore 
    private List<Customer> customers;
//skipped constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Hi @DeepanshuRathi, I trying for id which is already present in my database Account table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like that

```
private void _setPackAddress(Pack objectPack, Pack pacDao) {
        if (objectPack.getPackageAddress() != null) {
            pacDao.getPackageAddress().setCity(objectPack.getPackageAddress().getCity());
            pacDao.getPackageAddress().setNumber(objectPack.getPackageAddress().getNumber());
            pacDao.getPackageAddress().setPostalCode(objectPack.getPackageAddress().getPostalCode());
            pacDao.getPackageAddress().setStreet(objectPack.getPackageAddress().getStreet());
            
        }
}
```

And where can you see from where parameters come

```
        Pack pacDao = this.packRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new OpenApiResourceNotFoundException("Pack not found:: " + id));
```

not directly like that

```
private void _setPackAddress(Pack objectPack, Pack pacDao) {
 if (objectPack.getPackageAddress() != null) {
    pacDao.setPackageAddress(objectPack.getPackageAddress());
 }
}
```

I also encountered this problem, but I solved it that way.
I hope this post to be helpful for you.
Keep coding :-)

Comment: Is this the best way? If I had many attributes I'll have to update each and every attribute.
Or, can I get id from old object, assign to new object and save new object instead?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your model's ORM mapping generates model object's ID for each `save` operation (e.g. `@Generated Value(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`), and [`save()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) does **not** update record in that case.

Comment: Hi @Giorgi Tsiklauri, I am using same ORM mapping as suggested by you. Could you please suggest a solution here?

Comment: I didn't suggest any ORM mapping. ORM is an abstract programming facility, and in Java, it's often implemented with Hibernate JPA. Spring, also, uses that. Pay attention to your ID generation strategy (on top of `@Id` column) and look for what are the differences between different strategies.

Comment: Hi @Giorgi I have added my Account entity class. Could you please check it and tell me what can be the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your Account object have ID in it before you save, If ID is null for the object you're going to save, It'll be saved as new entry.

In your controller you can do this -

```
@PutMapping("/accounts/{id}")
public Account putAccount(@RequestBody Account account, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
    System.out.println(account);
    account.setId(id);
    Account ac = this.accountServices.addAccount(account);
    // save method of crud repository also updates if data is already present
    return ac;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Deepanshu Rathi, could u pls write complete handler method?